# follow a twitter account with in iPhone app using MGTwitterEngine

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need any source code by which I can  follow an account using MGTwitterEngine. It should be for iOS and please tell me if I can follow an account using oAuth or not.

Comment: Did you check out following post:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4210806/twitter-api-how-to-get-a-list-of-users-that-a-twitters-user-follow-mgtwitter

Kind regards,  
Bo

Comment: thanku for u r comment but in mentioned reference link we r getting list of followers while i need to follow an twitter account and can tell me what stuff i need to do this like consumerkey,secret key,ets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using the POST "friendships/create" method:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/post/friendships/create

Have you got the MGTwitterEngine authenticated and have a init'ed version of the _engine or do you need code for this?

If you have once authenticated you simply need to call the on the MGTwitterEngine:

- (NSString *)enableUpdatesFor:(NSString *)username; // friendships/create (follow username)

...to create a friendship.

Cheers
-JM

Comment: do we need to set accesstoken, to call this method?